# AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'setText'

Tags: python

I have to write an archery scoring program and I keep getting this error:
AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'setText'

```
def main():
    win = gameWindow()
    currentShot, overallScore = scoreOverlay(win)

    shot = 0
    totalScore = 0
    for i in range(5):
        p = win.getMouse()
        p.draw(win)
        x = p.getX
        y = p.getY
        score = scoring(p)

    currentShot.setText('Current Shot: {0:1}'.format(scoring))
    overallScore = 'overallScore' + 'currentShot'
    overallScore.setText('Total{0:1}'.format(overallScore))

    main()
```

Any ideas how to fix this? I am out of my depth on this one.
Thank you in advance for any help you may be able to provide.

Comment: `currentShot` and `overallScore` are integers...

Comment: Can you properly indent your code please?

Comment: @AndrewLi How would I change that?

Answer (score 0):

Here; `currentShot = 0` and here; `overallScore = 0` you are setting currentShot and overallScore as integers. They are no longer equal to `Text(Point(175,13), 'Current Shot:   ')` and `Text(Point(175,340), 'Total:   ')` respectively. Use different variable names for the variables in `currentShot = 0` and `overallScore = 0` and that should fix your error

Comment: That worked thank you, I ran into another problem after that and fixed it, and now have run into another. Now I get TypeError: non-empty format string passed to object.__format__

Comment: If I'm  following your code correctly, you need to change `currentShot.setText('Current Shot: {0:1}'.format(scoring))` to `currentShot.setText('Current Shot: {0:1}'.format(shot))` or `currentShot.setText('Current Shot: {0:1}'.format(score))`. (I'm not sure whether it's the shot or score variable you wish to use here, but either one it should also be converted to a string, for example `score = str(scoring(p))`) That is because here you are attempting to format a function, scoring(), and rather should be formatting a string.

Comment: Also, `overallScore = 'overallScore' + 'currentShot'` should be update to reflect your new variable names, `overallScore = shot + totalScore`

Comment: Sorry, that should be `totalScore = shot + totalScore`, and the next line `overallScore.setText('Total{0:1}'.format(overallScore))` should also be updated as `overallScore.setText('Total{0:1}'.format(totalScore))`... I hope this helps, I'm not entirely sure the end-goal of this script so I'm mostly shooting in the dark